# When is a high learning rate for Stochastic Gradient Descent a good thing?

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, gradient-descent, stochastic-gradient-descent

I was always under the impression that SGD needed a lower learning rate than optimizers like Adam, because it was stochastic and more likely to make training diverge with higher learning rates. I first learned this when I took [Andrew Ng's course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning) a few years back and I filed this fact into my mind...

A colleague of mine recently told me the opposite, that SGD usually uses a higher learning rate, and I didn't believe him. He told me to check [Pytorch's imagenet training loop](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/imagenet/main.py) to see.

he was right, but I am now confused about why I thought SGD needed a lower learning rate. It seems intuitive that the more stochastic SGD would make wild jumps with a high learning rate, so how can it be possible that using `0.1` on Imagenet can give better results?

Comment: adam is also stochastic (as is pretty much any optimizer used for nn training)

Comment: right, but all of the exponential moving averages in Adam make the optimization process less random and more targeted, so my implication was that Adam may be considered less stochastic than plain SGD